# How to get the values from a concatenated cell into the middle of a formula in another cell

Tags: excel-formula, hyperlink, concatenation, cell, formula

I'm trying to use info from a cell which has CONCATENATE info in it to create a formula/link which will pull through info from another workbook.

I currently have a spreadsheet with lots of links in it which helps me pull through information from other workbooks when I need it and I'm trying to make it a bit less manual set-up wise.

The formulas currently look like this and they work absolutely fine

```
='\\My computer\data\UBS2\1538\Electricity\[1538e13.xlsm]Tariff check'!$B$192
```

The [1538e13.xlsm] within the formula is currently changed individually per workbook I need to get info from (about 500-600 of them) and I'm looking for a way to make this a lot quicker.

The way I was hoping to solve this is by having have cells in the workbook which you enter the base info into (A2 = 1538, B2 = e, C2 = 13) and then a cell at the end of this to link it all together (`D2 =CONCATENATE(A2, B2, C2)`).

This I have done but now I'm look for a way to put the info from the concatenated D2 into the formula so there will be no need to manually change every link.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to do this that I just have no idea about, I've tried things like the below but nothing has worked thus far.

```
='\\My computer\data\UBS2\"&A2&"\Electricity\"&D2&".xlsm"Tariff check'!$B$192
```

Comment: Good news...Bad News...and potentially good news.  GOOD:  `INDIRECT` function will translate addresses as text into excel address for use and would work perfectly with your concatenate method.  BAD:  `INDIRECT` does not work with other workbooks unless they are open.  Potentially GOOD:  I understand this can be achieved through VBA.  Therefor you may want to drop the cell tag and replace it with excel-VBA.

Comment: On a side note, `CONCATENATE(A2, B2, C2)` is the same as `A2&B2&C2`  The later being just a bit shorter.